# Cannot connect to MySQL from remote server

Tags: networking, server, mysql, remote-access, azure

I cannot access MySQL server on my Ubuntu 16.04.02 VPS from Azure. I tried editing /etc/mysql/my.cnf but nothing - there is nothing like bind 127.0.0.1.
I created user with wildcard, but I am still getting connection refused.
What can I do?

my.cnf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

Output from terminal:

```
azure@pinf-vps:~$ sudo lsof -Pni :3306
COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  29117 mysql   15u  IPv4 2516519      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:3306 (LISTEN)
```

I have also doublechecked if the port is open on the VPS and in the firewall.

Thank you for help.

Comment: At the end of file 2 dirs with configs are included, you must search there for that `127.0.0.1`. This will narrow your search : `find /etc/mysql/conf.d/ -iname '*.cnf' | xargs grep 127 -sn` and `find /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ -iname '*.cnf' | xargs grep 127 -sn`

Comment: @bistoco - you helped me a lot! Thank you! It was in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubutu 16.04, the location of the config file you're looking for is `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`